# Escaped fragment or noscript for backbone/ajax applications and SEO

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, seo

I have an application that is Javascript heavy and uses Backbone to serve up content (HTML).

I'm looking to find the best solution to ensure this content gets indexed by Google.

I've came across two options:

1. Escaped fragment - have an alternate view that has static content
2. Noscript tag - have noscript on the url to render the content server side

Which solution should I use? Should I use both or one?

Also, how closely should the alternate version be without being penalized by Google? 
e.g. as the static views have no interaction and aren't seen by users, I can use considerably less HTML to serve up the same content; is it ok to do that?